# Tag closed/migrated question instead of or in addition to modifying the title

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, closed-questions, migrated-questions

when asking a question, users should avoid writing tags into the questions title which is automatically checked and results in the following error-message:

> Title contains a [tag] prefix; please use the tag field to enter tags instead

Anyway, when a question gets closed or is migrated from one stackexchange site to another, a "[closed]-" or "[migrated]-tag" is appended to the question's title. This is inconsistent and should be changed to the following behaviour:

- Introduce [closed](/questions/tagged/closed) and [migrated](/questions/tagged/migrated) as tags like all the other tags, too. (Maybe without the possibility to add them manually to avoid misuse - those tags should only be added/removed automatically - doesn't seem to be unusual, as there already are other tags with "special" meaning or behaviour like `[feature-request]` or `[faq]` here on meta)
- Add the `[closed]`- or `[migrated]`-tag to questions that get closed or migrated
- Don't append pseudo-tags to the questions title

Introducing `[closed]` and `[migrated]` tags would have the following advantages:

- It would be easier to search (for example: to review closed questions and check if they should be reopened)
- It would give us the ability to add these tags to our favourite tags (for example: to get migrated questions highlighted -- those are often some kind of interesting as they cover fields of different stackexchange sites (wich might be the reason the question was asked at the "wrong" place before))
- It would give us the ability to add these tags to our ignored tags (example: to ignore closed questions as they're closed anyway)

The only reason I can think of why the behavior is like it is at the moment, is because it's you can see that a question is closed at a glance - it's easier to see "[closed]" in the title than `[closed]` in the tag-list.

To obtain (and improve) this easy-to-see status of a question, the title might be changed additionally, but the pseudo-tags should be prepended instead of appended so they're even more obvious. This could look like one of these:

- CLOSED: After 15 years of programming, how does one get out of it?
- MIGRATED: Upgrading to Ubuntu 11.10 broke rabbitvcs
- closed: After 15 years of programming, how does one get out of it?
- migrated: Upgrading to Ubuntu 11.10 broke rabbitvcs
- {closed}: After 15 years of programming, how does one get out of it?
- {migrated}: Upgrading to Ubuntu 11.10 broke rabbitvcs

Note that i havn't listed the `[]`-syntax as this only confuses users - they can't add tags to the title manually, but obviously, there are questions that have this.

**EDIT:**
[Like adf said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109807/tag-closed-migrated-question-instead-of-or-in-addition-to-modifying-the-title/109810#109810), tags are usually there to

> [...]categorize the content of a question[...]

I agree with that, so my suggestion might not be the best -- but anyway, it would be nice to have an easy possibility to **search** for, **filter** and/or **ignore** closed or migrated questions, so I'll leave this question as is and hope somebody comes up with a better idea on how to achive this.

**PS:** at least here on meta, tags *are* used to categorize a questions status - just take a look at [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) and [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). this is exactly what I would like to achive with [closed](/questions/tagged/closed) and [migrated](/questions/tagged/migrated). These tags could also get a different visual style like the `status-*` tags here so the title changing can be completely avoided.

**PS²:** I found a third example where the same rules should be used: questions that are **community wiki**. it would be great to add a special [wiki](/questions/tagged/wiki) tag to those for the same reasons I've given above.

Comment: like expected, not everyone will agree with me, but a reason/explanation for downvotes would be nice anyway.

Comment: Your shift key seems to be broken.

Comment: @oezi: You said it yourself: people don't agree. Downvotes on meta mean "I don't agree with this"

Comment: I agree the [closed] shouldn't be in the actual title; perhaps just be shown like it is everywhere except in the title of the question.  Not sure if that is possible, tho.  It is very convenient to see that [closed] or [migrated] in the title.  Perhaps changing the delimeters?  Or just CAPITALIZING THE WORD?

Answer (score 10):

Tags categorize the *content* of a question, not its status.

You'd be confusing the issue of what tags are for by introducing tags for other purposes.

I'm not sure what else there is to say on the issue.

Comment: you're right, but there is a counterexample right here on meta: the `status-completed`- and `status-declined`-tags. those _are_ used to categorize status and are different from the other tags by using another visual styling. this is exactly what i would like to see for `closed` and `migrated` for all stackexchange-sites.

Comment: @oezi - things on meta should not be used to justify changes on the main site. They are two different things, by definition the **meta** site needs **meta** tags as it's about the site.

Answer (score 7):

### Tags are not the way to handle this:

> Anyway, when a question gets closed or is migrated from one stackexchange site to another, a "[closed]-" or "[migrated]-tag" is appended to the question's title. This is inconsistent

No... when a question is closed or migrated, *the title is modified to indicate that*. Those are not tags you're seeing. They're actually part of the title. There is no inconsistency here.

> Introduce [closed](/questions/tagged/closed) and [migrated](/questions/tagged/migrated) as tags like all the other tags, too.

That doesn't make sense. They're *not* "tags like all the other tags, too" -- all tags on the site talk about the topic of the question, E.G. the programming language, what the question is about, if it relates to particular software, if it's for a kind of algorithm, what kind of development it is, etc etc.

> Don't append pseudo-tags to the questions title

We're not. These are not tags.

> PS: at least here on meta, tags are used to categorize a questions status - just take a look at status-completed and status-declinet. this is exactly what I would like to achive with closed and migrated.

No. This is meta. Meta has three required tags, and lots of special tags. *Meta Stack Overflow Is Not Stack Overflow*. This is the golden rule of MSO. It's also why so many downvotes on your question was acceptable here -- downvotes are different on Meta. The logic "Meta does it this way so the main site should too" **does not work**.

---

### Now, on to *your real question:*

> but anyway, it would be nice to have an easy possibility to search for, filter and/or ignore closed or migrated questions, so I'll leave this question as is and hope somebody comes up with a better idea on how to achive this

I see what you're after here and I agree. You can [search for: `closed:1`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A1) and [`migrated:1`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=migrated%3A1) or even [`wiki:1`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=wiki%3A1) and that will give you all closed questions.

Conversely, you can [search for: `closed:0`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A0) to see only questions which are not closed. You can add additional search terms in there too, for example [all PHP questions that are not closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+closed%3A0) using `[php] closed:0`.

[The search tips page](https://stackoverflow.com/search) documents these options and many, many more.

It might be nice to have a UI option to hide closed questions. I would recommend asking that as a separate meta question since this one has been downvoted so much (because people don't agree with the "tags" suggestion)